# Mocking tightly coupled objects in PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, pdo, phpunit

For practice i'm creating my own database wrapper and query builder. When creating a `DatabaseConnection` object, a new PDO object is created in this object.

I have a `Database` class which depends on the `DatabaseConnection` object. This class builds the queries and executes them.

My `DatabaseConnection` class looks like this:

```
use PDO;

class DatabaseConnection
{
    /**
     * @var PDO $pdo The PDO connection object
     */
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct(array $credentials)
    {
        # Logic with $credentials to check on data
        $dsn = ...;
        # Open the connection
        $this->pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $credentials['username'], $credentials['password'], $options);
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the connection is open or closed
     *
     * @return bool Whether the connection is open or closed
     */
    public function isConnected() : bool
    {
        return $this->pdo !== null;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the PDO connection object
     *
     * @return PDO The PDO connection object
     */
    public function getPDO() : PDO
    {
        return $this->pdo;
    }

    /**
     * Closes the connection
     */
    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->pdo = null;
    }
}
```

When testing this, I ran across the problem that I always have to have a indentical database with the same login credentials on every computer i test this on.

For my research, I found out that I can create a mock objects, by doing

```
$pdo = $this->getMockBuilder('PDO')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();
```

The problem here is that I can't inject the `$pdo` object into my `DatabaseConnection` class.

What am I doing wrong and how can I test this class without using an actual database by mocking data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your mock, create a subtype of the **DatabaseConnection**, override the constructor and make the PDO object injectable. Then you can mock the PDO object and create the full mock for mocking operations.

Having ["news"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new) inside a constructor is a smell btw., your constructor should not do real work.

As you have found out while testing, this makes your type hard to test. Creating a mock on your own (by writing it out) can lighten up the darkened sky.

You might also not want to initialize the resources early, but connect to the database as late as possible. This would also move the new out of the constructor.

Comment: What do you mean by "news"? Should I make a `connect` method or something?

Comment: new Object, the new operator. I can't say if your object needs a connect  method, connecting the resource could be implicit, that depends on the API you need to provide in your practicing. You can inject a factory object that has a creational method to provide the **PDO** object. You can then replace the factory with one that is mocking the **PDO** object. The factory would be for testing only.

Comment: I'm confused, do you mean my `Database` class should take in a `PDO` object, which is mocked from something else?

Comment: Yes, your database class depends on PDO, so it should require it as a constructor parameter.

Comment: Why shouldn't I use the `DatabaseConnection` class as a parameter then? The reason I did this was for checking if the connection was active. Doesn't this make the `DatabaseConnection` class unnessacery?

Comment: Perhaps. Both **PDO** and **DatabaseConnection** are representing a database-connection and therefore one could argue that only one of them is needed. But as you wrote, you'd like to do some practice here, I can imagine that despite **DatabaseConnection** might be superfluous, you explicitly want it for practicing. -- And you can use the **DatabaseConnection** as a parameter. That's not wrong.

Comment: But that wouldn't be a database wrapper if i would remove that class right? Is there no reason why I would keep that class? I would finally wanted to use this in production aswell.

Comment: We perhaps discuss too much. Solve your testing problem and decide on the other questions later. I can only give limited help b/c I don't know about your scenario and needs, I can only provide more generic pointers and suggestions.

Comment: I see. But when extending the `DatabaseConnection` for injecting the `PDO` object, I can't set the private field to the `PDO` object. I need this because the `Database` class is using the `getPDO()` method for running queries of that. Is there another way?

Comment: Yes, you can't. But you can create a protected setter in the base-class or turn it from private to protected.

Comment: I think I'm going to solve my design issues first, this doesn't solve the problem right? It's just a way around?

Comment: It is not possible to just solve design issues. You run across design issues and then you can fix them. What you describe as way around: With every solution there are pros and cons. There are consequences. Important part here is that you are more aware at which points things tend to break / stand in your way. For example `new` inside a constructor. For practice try with the mock. If you get the tests to run, change the design (e.g. move from setter injection to ctor injection). Then adopt the tests and you will see how it feels and if that really is a design improvement.